# How to open a doc or pdf document from Odoo website?

Tags: html, odoo, odoo-8

How can we open a word document or pdf file by clicking on any link in Odoo? What are the steps need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

1) Install module **Document Management System (document)**.

2) Create directory (knowledge menu unit) or use existing one. Attach to this category required file (button "Attachments" above the form)

3) Since it was downloaded, it would generate an url. To access it: mouse right click on downloaded file - save url

4) Add the url to the website. Pressing it will download the file (publically available).

> Note : Above Functionlity Work on odoo 8.
>
> Document Management System module Remove in odoo 9 community and enterprice so this all file store in ir.attachment model.

So. Programatically, it is pretty much the same. The module 'document' allows to attach files to any object, including product.product (or product.template). So you have to find it:

attachment_ids = self.env['ir.attachment'].search([('res_model','=','product.product'),('res_id','=',product.id)]).

Where product.id - is id of needed product. E.g. you can store attachment_ids in product.product class as one2many field. After that you can get an url of any attachment. For example, for binary files:

for attach in attachment_ids:
            url = 'https://yourcompany.com'+'/web/binary/saveas?model=ir.attachment&field=datas&filename_field=name&id='+str(attach.id)

This url may be easily added to the website product site, using foreach in product.attachment_ids

Comment: I already checked this Jainik, I dont want it to be downloaded

Comment: so you can check the website_slides module

Comment: Ok thank you Jainik Patel, I will check it and let you know

Comment: What i found is,it is a different page and channel kindoff Jainik. what i wanted is like in the website - http://www.bizzcloud.nl/ check the website's terms and conditions link at the bottom of the page, it opens up a pdf in a new tab